# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; 49.0686 nan]'

Tags: ios, uitableview, calayer

I have a tableView with custom cells. each of the cells has a UIView inside and a UILabel.

The data for the first two cells are fine - when I scroll in the third one the app crashes with the error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; 49.0686 nan]'
```

The code that this is happening is this :

```
BarView *bar = [[BarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((barFullWidth - barWidth)/2 + _index*(barFullWidth),  plotView.height - roundf([[barInfo objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue]*barHeightRatio), barWidth, roundf([[barInfo objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue]*barHeightRatio))];
```

which calls this :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
```

Where should I look at? I cannot even understand what this error means.

The bar is the UIView inside the cell. The bar itself is created and is visible, even though the app crashes.

Comment: Your bar view is the cell? Or is that bar view inside the cell? 
Maybe a little more code for context?

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto the bar is the view inside the cell.

Comment: Just for a sanity check, try to create a CGRect first, nslog it and then call init with frame. Something is setting that view's layer bounds to zero, and your override of init seems correct (just missing the return self;)

Comment: In the line it fails I do see that :

 {{0, nan}, {49.06863, nan}}

that means that by y and height are nan for a reason.

Comment: Exactly. Those values are the ones from the NSLog? Or from the stack of the exception?

Comment: And the curious part is that your roundf values are the ones returning nan.

Comment: These values are from  the NSLog. I found the value that is ausing that, now I have to find out why. Thanks!